# MySQL (SQL in general) limiting columns

Tags: mysql, sparse-matrix

Without the correct phrase it's hard to describe this, so I will give an example. Consider the following Data:

```
colA     colB      colC      colD      colE
------------------------------------------------
Hello     from                        
          this      is        
Can                           i         
                                        please?
But       also      all       columns   pop'd
```

As you can see, many columns are actually empty. In the end, I would like to get the following output:

```
col1     col2      col3      col4      col5
------------------------------------------------
Hello     from
this      is
Can       i
please?
But       also      all       columns   pop'd
```

Basically, the data is shifted to the left. I thought of using a CASE WHEN statement, but this gets pretty complex since it's actually 7 columns (not 5 as outlined in the example above).

What would be the most efficient way to get that result. The name of the resultant columns doesn't matter, they are renamed in any case.

Comment: are there only ever going to be at most two values per row?

Comment: No, all 7 columns may be populated as well ... I'll adapt the example.

Comment: ugh. then there's no simple query

Comment: What would you recommend if we're able to limit them to .. say ... 3 ?

Comment: if there is an input row with all seven values filled, how many output columns do you want?

Comment: Ideally: 7; But I could probably also do with 3 :) (If there is no nice solution for 7)

Comment: Normalise your design

Comment: will any of the columns have more than one word?

Comment: Yes. But I think I will change the design as there is no apparently "easy" solution.

Comment: Pretty sure my answer will support multi word columns its why I didn't use a space as the delimiter

Comment: are the blanks empty or null?

Answer (score 0):

Treating this as nothing more than a thought exercise, because it seems like something best left to a better structure, or done at the application level - you can accomplish what you want with a single, horrendously ugly query, like this:

```
SELECT substring_index(substring_index(CONCAT (
                trim(leading '#@' FROM trim(trailing '#@' FROM replace(replace(replace(concat_ws('#@', cola, colb, colc, cold, cole), '#@#@', '#@~!'), '~!#@', ''), '~!', ''))),
                '#@'
                ), '#@', 1), '#@', - 1) col1,
    substring_index(substring_index(CONCAT (
                trim(leading '#@' FROM trim(trailing '#@' FROM replace(replace(replace(concat_ws('#@', cola, colb, colc, cold, cole), '#@#@', '#@~!'), '~!#@', ''), '~!', ''))),
                '#@'
                ), '#@', 2), '#@', - 1) col2,
    substring_index(substring_index(CONCAT (
                trim(leading '#@' FROM trim(trailing '#@' FROM replace(replace(replace(concat_ws('#@', cola, colb, colc, cold, cole), '#@#@', '#@~!'), '~!#@', ''), '~!', ''))),
                '#@'
                ), '#@', 3), '#@', - 1) col3,
    substring_index(substring_index(CONCAT (
                trim(leading '#@' FROM trim(trailing '#@' FROM replace(replace(replace(concat_ws('#@', cola, colb, colc, cold, cole), '#@#@', '#@~!'), '~!#@', ''), '~!', ''))),
                '#@'
                ), '#@', 4), '#@', - 1) col4,
    substring_index(substring_index(CONCAT (
                trim(leading '#@' FROM trim(trailing '#@' FROM replace(replace(replace(concat_ws('#@', cola, colb, colc, cold, cole), '#@#@', '#@~!'), '~!#@', ''), '~!', ''))),
                '#@'
                ), '#@', 5), '#@', - 1) col5
FROM yourtable;
```

The gist of it is, we create a single delimited string containing all columns using `concat_ws` (i'm using `#@` as the delimiter - it can be whatever. the idea is its unlikely to appear in your string).  We then, though a series of `replace` calls, convert all multiple occurrences of the delimiter to a single occurence. With two calls to `trim` we get rid of the delimiter from the front and end of the string, and then add it back in to the end of all strings with `concat`. We can then extract the word at each position in the string using `substring_index`. The trailing delimiter ensures we can get an empty result if there are no more words in that string. Repeat this once for every column, incrementing the offset to the inner `substring_index` call, depending on which virtual column you're creating.

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f699/15)

If you want to extend this to seven columns, just repeat the field twice more, and increment the offset each time.

Comment: Some thoughts are better left unthunk :-(